# Initialize and terminate a bot on EC2 remotely

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I am trying to run a script to start, stop, or restart a bot from my front end webpage.

I have a bot that runs almost 24/7 on a Linux EC2 instance, and a webpage front end that allows for parameter input and shows the current status of the bot. The front end sends a POST request to a lambda function, which writes the parameters to my S3 bucket. The script to start the bot on the EC2 instance pulls the latest parameters from S3 and initializes the bot. When the bot starts up and shuts down, it writes the status ("running", "stopped") to a file in the S3 bucket, which then shows on the front end.

I have looked into SSM Run Command with Lambda, but given that the bot runs for days at a time, I don't believe that's viable. Additionally, it uses an agent to connect, so trying to use the `screen` command would terminate when the agent terminates.

I have also tried adding the script to my EC2 instance’s User Data, but that does not seem to work. Similarly a cron job for reboot does not work.

I've considered using a trigger file in S3, i.e. having the EC2 instance check at a given time interval for some trigger file in S3 that would indicate a start or stop, but that seems very resource intensive.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: You could use a  lambda function to do that. This article is leveraging event bridge but you could do it without it. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-eventbridge/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: @JulienB. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the link you provided is for starting and stopping instances, not sending commands to the EC2's terminal or ssh-ing. I was hoping to use lambda, but I can't seem to find a way to send a command via Lambda, outside of SSM which I mentioned above.

Comment: Oh! I really did not understand what you were asking for. That is something different indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was setting up a crontab job that runs on reboot, then starting, stopping, and restarting the EC2 instance with a lambda function.

Steps to resolve this for anyone in the same boat:

1. SSH into the EC2 instance
2. `crontab -e`
3. add the following line:
   `@reboot sleep 60 && cd /home/ec2-user/bot_folder/ && /usr/bin/screen -S bot -dm /usr/bin/python3 run_bot.py`
   (for vim, press `i` to enter insert mode, paste the line and make changes, then press `esc` `:wq` `enter` to save)

Ensure that the script has all of its paths specified absolutely. In my case, using Selenium, the chromedriver path needed to be specified.

Finally, setup a lambda function to start/stop/reboot your instance as the comment above [referenced](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-eventbridge/?nc1=h_ls).